# How to access application inside subfolder in CI?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a project in codeigniter. directory structure is like below.

> frontend
>     |_application
>      |*assets
>     ..
>
>      ..
>     |* mobileapps
>         |_ adminpanel
>                  |_application
>                  |_assets...

Frontend represent frontend website.inside mobileapps folder I have put my adminpanel code, now I want to access the adminpanel. How can I achieve this?

Can anyone help me to do this?
Frontend is a separate codeigniter setup, and adminpanel is also separate codeigniter setup.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the same application directory .first you can set the routes fixed 
for frontend/.. for frontend and admin/.. for admin. this is the basic routes for change  the controllers and views based on  frontend and admin panel thats all....